# How to get UTC offset (timezone) in correct format?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, strftime, gmt

I have code like this that converts an Epoch timestamp into GMT timestamp:

```
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

std::string getDateTimeZ(size_t epoch)
{
  const time_t time = epoch;
  const auto timeInfo = *localtime(&time);
  std::array<char, 80> buffer;
  std::strftime(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", &timeInfo);
  return buffer.data();
}
```

This works fine, except that my timestamp is e.g.:

`2020-09-10T20:53:10+0300`

I'd like it to be:

`2020-09-10T20:53:10+03:00`

How can I do this out-of-the-box without an ugly and error-prone hack on the resulting string? I don't see any other options to get the offset besides `%z`.

Some other library like Boost would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [preview of the C++20 `<chrono>` facilities](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), which works with C+11:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string
getDateTimeZ(std::size_t epoch)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_seconds zt{current_zone(), sys_seconds{seconds{epoch}}};
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << format("%FT%T%Ez", zt);
    return os.str();
}
```

The trick with this library is to use `%Ez` in place of `%z`.

This library *does* require [some installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).